# Setting ImageView from cursor

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the imageView from Uri (in a sqlite database column) returned by cursor but its not working.

Code:

```
mCursor = mydb.rawQuery("select * from events;", null);
 if (mCursor != null ) {
     mCursor.moveToFirst();

String[] from = new String[]{DbHandler.column_id, DbHandler.column_name, DbHandler.column_location, DbHandler.column_date, DbHandler.img_loc};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.photoInDb};
SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCurs = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listviewfinal, mCursor, from, to);
 simpleCurs.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                @Override
                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int i) {

                if (view instanceof ImageView) {

                    ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
                    // just to see what is returned by this!
                    Log.d("orange", "images: " + cursor.getString(i));
                    Bitmap thumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(i)), 320, 240);
                    image.setImageBitmap(thumbImage);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
                }
            });
            listView.setAdapter(simpleCurs);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting image url from the database?

Comment: yes. there is a column that has photo's Uri that are saved on sdcard. the Log.d line returns "images: file:///storage/sdcard0/DCIM/OrangeClubPhotos/1370853592867.jpg" - and the file exists. so the problem is that it's not setting the files in imageviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,It should work if you are getting image path correctly.

```
Bitmap thumbImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
image.setImageBitmap(thumbImage );
```

**EDIT:**

I think you are having some problem with getting image path. Do as follows to get the path.

```
String imagePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() "folderpath/imageaname.jpg";
```

In your case folderpath is **DCIM/OrangeClubPhotos/** and image name is **1370853592867.jpg**

Comment: have tried this and no luck. the path is in DbHandler.img_loc which is supposed to be set in R.id.photoInDb via setViewValue method. problem should be somewhere in setViewValue!

Comment: thanks for the code but image's path are not kinda static. one image per row in database which should be assigned to the view in listview along side its other 4 textviews.

Answer (score 0):

Writer these simple lines

```
URL url = new URL("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

or try this

```
File imgFile = new  File(“/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg”);
if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Comment: this is a useful snippet but not want i need. i dont want to show another photo in my imageview. i have the path of my photos returned by cursor. just wanna load them in imageview.

Comment: you just need to replace the given path with your required path

Comment: yes, and im struggling to see what is the correct path according to my code above. any idea?